# How to make a Django FormSet accept m2m but store them as multiple FK records?

Tags: django

I need to provide a test for students, but some questions accept multiple answer.

Can I make it create multiple records for storing multiple answers instead of using a M2M?

e.g. if a student select A and B for a question, would act like the following:

```
StudentAnwer.objects.create(question=question, answer=answer_a)
StudentAnwer.objects.create(question=question, answer=answer_b)
```

formsets.py

```
from django import forms

StudentAnswerFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Student,
    StudentAnswer,
    fields=['question', 'answer', ],
    formset=forms.BaseInlineFormSet)
```

models.py

```
class Question(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_multiple = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class StudentAnswer(BaseModel):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='answers')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='student_answers')
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name='student_answers')
```

views.py

```
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

class StudentWizardView(SessionWizardView):
    ...

    def get_answer_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        ...

        question_list = get_question_list()

        return forms.inlineformset_factory(
            Student,
            StudentAnswer,
            fields=['question', 'answer', ],
            extra=len(question_list),
            formset= forms.BaseInlineFormSet)

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(StudentWizardView, self).get_form(step, data, files)

        # determine the step if not given
        if step is None:
            step = self.steps.current

        if step == self.STEP_ANSWER:
            initial_dict = self.get_form_initial(step)

            prev_form_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(self.STEP_PROFILE)

            form = self.get_answer_form(step, data, files)

            for form_index in range(len(initial_dict.keys())):
                question = initial_dict[form_index]['question']

                answer_list = question.get_answer_list()

                if question.is_multiple:
                    form.forms[form_index].fields['answer'] = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=answer_list,
                                                                                   widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)
                else:
                    form.forms[form_index].fields['answer'].widget.choices.queryset = answer_list
```

I'm trying to avoid M2M for making it easier to display the possible answers per question on the template.

```
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{{ wizard.form.management_form }}

{% for answer_form in wizard.form.forms %}
  {{ answer_form.question }}
  {{ answer_form.answer }}

  {% for hidden in answer_form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by using raw `form.data` instead of `form.cleaned_data`, so could access multiple values for the same field before they were cleaned up.

That's risky, but you can replicate the cleanup method for just the parts you want it to act.

Also made a custom checkbox list by:

```
{% for choice in field.field.choices %}
  <input type="checkbox" id="id_{{ field.html_name }}_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="{{ field.html_name }}" value="{{ choice.id }}"{% if choice.id in field.value %} checked="checked"{% endif %}> {{ choice }}
{% endfor %}
```

And removed the custom form field, so all of them are:

```
form.forms[form_index].fields['answer'].widget.choices.queryset = answer_list
```